# Is there a superhero who has notably super-strong teeth?

Tags: super-hero, my-little-pony, my-little-pony-fim, powers

*My Little Pony: Friendship is Magic* season 5 episode 18 “Crusaders of the Lost Mark” has a colt with “**super teeth**”, who can lift a heavy see-saw by grabbing one end with his teeth.

[image: Yellow colt lifting see-saw with his teeth, screenshot from S5 E8]

(This pony reappears in [S5 E24](http://mlp.wikia.com/wiki/File:Rara_with_super-teeth_colt_and_Sweetie_Belle_S5E24.png) and [S6 E19](http://mlp.wikia.com/wiki/File:Gabby_giving_Carrot_Crunch_braces_S6E19.png), and gets dental braces in the latter.  He is unnamed in the show, has a yellow coat, green punk-style hair, and three carrots as a cutie mark.  The fan nickname is Carrot Crunch.)

We know that lifting heavy objects with his teeth is a remarkable ability, at least for a foal, because Diamond Tiara mentions it.  (Without this remark, it would be hard to judge how rare this ability is.  Earth ponies do sometimes grab objects with their mouth, and S3 E3 and S2 E20 demonstrates that they pull ropes with their mouth.  But the strength of ponies is generally portrayed in a very inconsistent manner in this show: ponies always have as much or as little strength as suits the plot.)

**Are the super-teeth a reference to a superhero from outside the *Friendship is Magic* universe?**  Is there another superhero or supervillain who is definitely portrayed as lifting heavy objects with his teeth, preferably in a way where they grab a horizontal object by one end so that it's obviously unbalanced?  Is there perhaps one of them who this pony is trying to resemble (eg. male, has similar colors)?

I'd be interested about this super-power appearing in any fantasy or science fiction media, be it comic strips, live action films or anything else.

Comment: [Krypto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krypto) comes to mind...

Comment: One could Argue Superman, Wolverine and Deadpool.  Superman has an insane ammount of strenght, his teeth wouldn't be different. Wolverine has metalic teeth (His bones are made of metal and teeth are bones), meaning his teeth would be extremely strong aswell. And Deadpool... Well, he can break the laws of physics.

Comment: @Oak: yeah, I was wondering if I should include a sentence about characters with godlike powers who could presumably have this effect.  But I'm hoping “portrayed as lifting heavy objects with his teeth” (as opposed to “able to lift heavy object with his teeth”) is enough to make it clear what kind of answers I want.

Comment: Hmm, does Galactus actually eat planets?

Comment: @Oak Teeth are not bones.

Comment: This question bothers me. It's arguably on topic, but has spawned a range of upvoted but irrelevant answers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first one that came to mind is a super villain rather than a superhero, and that is [Jaws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaws_(James_Bond)) from James Bond.

Here he is in action:

[image]

And here as his normal charming self :)

[image]

Answer (score 15):

[Matter Eater Lad!](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Tenzil_Kem_%28Pre-Zero_Hour%29)
Matter-Eater Lad can eat any substance in any amount at super-speed. He can consume an unlimited amount of matter in any form - solid, liquid or gas. He once hollowed out a large meteor in a matter of minutes.
Digestive Enzymes: Their power to eat hard objects, like steel, without having super-strength or invulnerability, stems from the Bismollian ability to produce a variety of digestive enzyme that act on specific substances, making them easier to chew and digest. Once, when Computo had robbed him of his matter-eating ability, he could still produce enzymes, but biting into a piece of steel hurt his teeth. 
[image]

Answer (score 7):

**Trap-Jaw**, a villain cyborg from He-Man (and the Masters of the Universe) comes to mind:

[image: Trap Jaw eats some Eternium, the most powerful mineral on the planet]

Trap Jaw eating some Eternium, the most powerful mineral on the planet

[image: Trap-Jaw bites Teela's sword...]

Trap-Jaw bites Teela's sword.

Answer (score 7):

**[Squirrel Girl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squirrel_Girl)** can bite with 1,085,000 pounds of pressure.

This is revealed in issue 33 of [The Unbeatable Squirrel Girl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Unbeatable_Squirrel_Girl).

[image: page from Squirrel Girl]

> Guys, I've always had the **proportional** abilities of a squirrel. Tail like they have, but scaled up to human size. Leaping like they do, but scaled up to human size.
>
> But the thing most people forget about squirrels is their **incredible** jaws.
>
> They need them to bite through **nuts**, you know? Our human jaw muscles are among the strongest we've got, and they produce around two hundred pounds per square inch of pressure. But **squirrel** jaws can produce **seven thousand** pounds per square inch.
>
> Scale **that** up to human size, and well--
>
> --I can bite with **one million** and eighty-five thousand pounds of pressure.

[image: chomp]

I doubt "Carrot Crunch" is a reference to Squirrel Girl (in fact I doubt it's a reference to anything specific), but if you're looking for people with super-strong teeth, Squirrel Girl should be on the list.

Answer (score 6):

Not so much a superhero, but [Sunny Baudelaire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunny_Baudelaire) comes to mind...

Answer (score 6):

### Within Marvel comics, we have Lockjaw.

[image]

Technically [Marvel Universe](http://marvel.com/universe/Lockjaw)  only mentions an "enhanced strength in his jaw".

> He also has an increased sense of smell and a strength in his jaw which may be due to his immense size.

But [Marvel Wikia](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Lockjaw_%28Earth-616%29) expands on this explanation, explaining that Lockjaw was able to trap The Thing with his bite.

> Lockjaw possesses great physical strength simply from size alone. Due to his canine physiology he is limited to what he can pick up by its shape, that is, whether he can hold it with his mouth. His mouth, however, is unusually large, as is his head, which is about 40 inches from flews to dome. His jaw strength is such that he once clamped onto the Thing's hand and the Thing was apparently unable to free it.